# Script resets elements after deletion on Website

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

Trying to code an adblocker for a website on which no adblockers work.

I'm using vanilla JS and this is what I have been testing with:

```
let test = document.querySelector('div[style="margin: 0 auto;margin-top:25px;"]');

test.parentNode.removeChild(test);
```

Now, this works when I select the home-page-body, which is the entire page, but when I select something like above mentioned (this is a small banner ad), after the page loads, it isn't there but re-appears after a second or two (takes more time to load, because, well, it's deleted and some script is reloading it).

I have no idea which script it is, how to detect it. I have tried searching it with element ids as keywords. To see if some script has that specific ID name in it.

Anyone have any suggestions? Website is: [net.adjara.com](https://net.adjara.com)

Comment: removing a script tag doesnt remove the javascript. the loaded script probably added a mutation observer which you would have to undo/ delete/ unbind.

Comment: I have no idea what a mutation observer is. I guess the script is loaded, got any references I can use to learn more about it?

Comment: well youre free to read about it. could be an interval or mutation observer. anyways. once a script is loaded the javascript is being run. removing a script tag from the document doesnt undo the javascript.

Comment: Ask yourself why "no adblockers work" - what's stopping the other adblockers working?

Comment: when i delete an ad it doesnt come back though. can you give a hint which ad youre talking about in particular?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1qwD45W

Basically, I set the querySelector to id of this specific element. If you delete it manually, it deletes it and it doesn't come back. But I think i came to a new problem.
When I try to select it after the page loads, it won't.
I set a timer and I get "cannot read property 'parentNode' of null at deletor".

Code:
let test = document.querySelector("#slider-wrapper");

var timer = setInterval(deleter, 4000);

function deletor() {
 timer;
 test.parentNode.removeChild(test);
};

Comment: Seems like the selector can't even detect the element after said time.

Comment: Btw Adblock Plus seems to work on this website

Comment: Doesn't, well, partly.